# Generic function to clear all handlers of a procedure?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, function, handler

I need to write a generic function which will be used to remove all the event handlers of a **Sub** and a **Func** (I need the generic function to work properly with both, subroutines and functions).

...The problem is I don't know how to do this, I saw examples declaring delegates but that's not generic like I precise.

I've read this article on CodeProject but the code is in C# I can't understand any: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103542/Removing-Event-Handlers-using-Reflection

This is the only I can do by myself:

```
Public Class Form1

    ' Call the function to remove all the handlers of "MySub"
    ' Clear_Handles(Of MySub)

    Private Function Clear_Handles(Of T)(ByVal MethodName As T)
        ' Code to remove all handlers(of "MethodName")
    End Function

    Private Sub MySub() Handles event1, event2, event3
        ' bla bla bla
    End Sub

End Class
```

Thanks for read.

> UPDATE

I've tried to convert the code above to VB just to try it but I can't use it, I don't know how to use it, this is what I've done:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub MySub() Handles Button1.Click, Button2.click
    ' Do nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' Attempting to remove "Button1.Click" and "Button2.click" events of "MySub()"
    PSLib.cEventHelper.RemoveAllEventHandlers(MySub)
End Sub

End Class
```

...This is the translated code, I don't know if it works 'cause I don't know how to use the methods:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Management
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Text

Namespace PSLib
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Public NotInheritable Class cEventHelper
        Private Sub New()
        End Sub
        Shared dicEventFieldInfos As New Dictionary(Of Type, List(Of FieldInfo))()

        Private Shared ReadOnly Property AllBindings() As BindingFlags
            Get
                Return BindingFlags.IgnoreCase Or BindingFlags.[Public] Or BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.[Static]
            End Get
        End Property

        '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Private Shared Function GetTypeEventFields(t As Type) As List(Of FieldInfo)
            If dicEventFieldInfos.ContainsKey(t) Then
                Return dicEventFieldInfos(t)
            End If

            Dim lst As New List(Of FieldInfo)()
            BuildEventFields(t, lst)
            dicEventFieldInfos.Add(t, lst)
            Return lst
        End Function

        '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Private Shared Sub BuildEventFields(t As Type, lst As List(Of FieldInfo))
            ' Type.GetEvent(s) gets all Events for the type AND it's ancestors
            ' Type.GetField(s) gets only Fields for the exact type.
            '  (BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy only works on PROTECTED & PUBLIC
            '   doesn't work because Fieds are PRIVATE)

            ' NEW version of this routine uses .GetEvents and then uses .DeclaringType
            ' to get the correct ancestor type so that we can get the FieldInfo.
            For Each ei As EventInfo In t.GetEvents(AllBindings)
                Dim dt As Type = ei.DeclaringType
                Dim fi As FieldInfo = dt.GetField(ei.Name, AllBindings)
                If fi IsNot Nothing Then
                    lst.Add(fi)
                End If
            Next

        End Sub

        '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Private Shared Function GetStaticEventHandlerList(t As Type, obj As Object) As EventHandlerList
            Dim mi As MethodInfo = t.GetMethod("get_Events", AllBindings)
            Return DirectCast(mi.Invoke(obj, New Object() {}), EventHandlerList)
        End Function

        '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Public Shared Sub RemoveAllEventHandlers(obj As Object)
            RemoveEventHandler(obj, "")
        End Sub

        '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Public Shared Sub RemoveEventHandler(obj As Object, EventName As String)
            If obj Is Nothing Then
                Return
            End If

            Dim t As Type = obj.[GetType]()
            Dim event_fields As List(Of FieldInfo) = GetTypeEventFields(t)
            Dim static_event_handlers As EventHandlerList = Nothing

            For Each fi As FieldInfo In event_fields
                If EventName <> "" AndAlso String.Compare(EventName, fi.Name, True) <> 0 Then
                    Continue For
                End If

                ' After hours and hours of research and trial and error, it turns out that
                ' STATIC Events have to be treated differently from INSTANCE Events...
                If fi.IsStatic Then
                    ' STATIC EVENT
                    If static_event_handlers Is Nothing Then
                        static_event_handlers = GetStaticEventHandlerList(t, obj)
                    End If

                    Dim idx As Object = fi.GetValue(obj)
                    Dim eh As [Delegate] = static_event_handlers(idx)
                    If eh Is Nothing Then
                        Continue For
                    End If

                    Dim dels As [Delegate]() = eh.GetInvocationList()
                    If dels Is Nothing Then
                        Continue For
                    End If

                    Dim ei As EventInfo = t.GetEvent(fi.Name, AllBindings)
                    For Each del As [Delegate] In dels
                        ei.RemoveEventHandler(obj, del)
                    Next
                Else
                    ' INSTANCE EVENT
                    Dim ei As EventInfo = t.GetEvent(fi.Name, AllBindings)
                    If ei IsNot Nothing Then
                        Dim val As Object = fi.GetValue(obj)
                        Dim mdel As [Delegate] = TryCast(val, [Delegate])
                        If mdel IsNot Nothing Then
                            For Each del As [Delegate] In mdel.GetInvocationList()
                                ei.RemoveEventHandler(obj, del)
                            Next
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End Sub

    End Class
End Namespace
```

> UPDATE

This is an example of I will do:

```
private sub form1_shown() handles me.shown
    RemoveAll_EventHandlers(of MyMethod)
    ' So it will remove: button1.click, button2.click, button3.click 
end sub

Private sub MyMethod() handles button1.click, button2.click, button3.click
   ' Nothing to do here. . . 
end sub

public sub RemoveAll_EventHandlers(of T)(byval MethodName as T)
      For each evt as event in MethodName : removehandler control.event, addres of(T) 
end sub
```

> UPDATE:

Another example for your imagination... :

```
Private Sub RemoveAll_EventHandlers(Of T)(ByVal MethodName As T)
    For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
        For Each evt As EventHandler In Control
            RemoveHandler ctrl.evt, addresof(T)
        Next
    Next
End Sub

private sub form1_shown() handles me.shown
    RemoveAll_EventHandlers(of MyMethod)
    ' So it will remove: button1.click, button2.click, button3.click 
end sub

Private sub MyMethod() handles button1.click, button2.click, button3.click
   ' Nothing to do here. . . 
end sub
```

Comment: You don't really need to understand C#.  The code is ready to be compiled as a .dll, or include the code as a separate project in your solution.   Then it's just a matter of adding it as a reference, and importing the namespace.  The article shows you how to call the functions, just drop the semi-colon.

Comment: @tinstaafl Thankyou I don't noticed that, but now I'm trying to use the class and I can't use it by writting the name of the procedure as an argument, then how to use it? please see my updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in C# but it is generic. From what I understand you have a class that has a bunch of events.  You will have the same method subscribe to multiple events.  You want to remove the method from all events it is subscribed to. I wrote a quick test, might be some corner cases

```
    public static class EventUtility
        {
            public static void Unsubscribe(object obj, Delegate method)
            {
                Type type = obj.GetType();
                foreach (EventInfo eventInfo in type.GetEvents(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance))
                {
                    FieldInfo field = type.GetField(eventInfo.Name, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                    Delegate eventDelegate = field.GetValue(obj) as Delegate;
                    foreach (Delegate subscriber in eventDelegate.GetInvocationList())
                    {
                        if (subscriber.Method == method.Method)
                        {
                            eventInfo.RemoveEventHandler(obj, subscriber);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public class TestClass
        {
            public event EventHandler EventA;
            public event EventHandler EventB;
            public event EventHandler EventC;

            public void A()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A Start");
                EventA(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                Console.WriteLine("A End");
            }

            public void B()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("B Start");
                EventB(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                Console.WriteLine("B End");
            }
            public void C()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("C Start");
                EventC(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                Console.WriteLine("C End");
            }

        }

        class Program
        {
            public static void test2()
            {
                TestClass t = new TestClass();
                t.EventA += Handler1;
                t.EventB += Handler1;
                t.EventC += Handler1;

                t.EventA += Handler2;
                t.EventB += Handler2;
                t.EventC += Handler2;

                t.EventA += Handler3;
                t.EventB += Handler3;
                t.EventC += Handler3;

                t.A();
                t.B();
                t.C();

                EventUtility.Unsubscribe(t, new EventHandler(Handler2));

                t.A();
                t.B();
                t.C();
            }


            private static void Handler1(object instance, EventArgs args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("handler1 invoked.");
            }

            private static void Handler2(object instance, EventArgs args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("handler2 invoked.");
            }

            private static void Handler3(object instance, EventArgs args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("handler3 invoked.");
            }

            static void Main()
            {
                test2();
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
For Each b As Button in MySub.Controls.OfType(Of Button)

    'This should remove all the handlers for each button
    PSLib.cEventHelper.RemoveAllEventHandlers(b)

    'Or like this to just remove just the Click handler for each button
    PSLib.cEventHelper.RemoveEventHandler(b, "Click")

Next
```

A suggestion use the original first.  Get your front interfacing with it properly.  Then do the translation.  This way you have a base line and know how it's supposed to work.

UPDATE:

I think part of the confusion is in the misuse of terminology.  In your update MyMethod is a handler, it doesn't contain handlers, but it can handle more than one event.  Button1.Click is an event.  Button1 is a Button.  So, using the proper terminology, it appears you want to remove all the events(Button1.Click,Button2.Click, etc.) being handled by a specific handler(MyMethod).

Here's one way, assuming that all the controls are the same:

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each b As Control In Me.Controls
        If b.Name.Contains("3") OrElse b.Name.Contains("4") Then
            b.Tag = New KeyValuePair(Of String, Boolean)("1", True)
            AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf Button_Click1
        Else
            b.Tag = New KeyValuePair(Of String, Boolean)("2", True)
            AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf Button_Click2
        End If
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub RemoveEvents(Handler As String)
    For Each b As Control In Me.Controls
        Dim TempTag As KeyValuePair(Of String, Boolean) = DirectCast(b.Tag, KeyValuePair(Of String, Boolean))
        If TempTag.Key = Handler AndAlso TempTag.Value = False Then
            Select Case Handler
                Case "1"
                    RemoveHandler b.Click, AddressOf Button_Click1
                Case "2"
                    RemoveHandler b.Click, AddressOf Button_Click2
            End Select
        End If
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub Button_Click1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'do stuff
End Sub
Private Sub Button_Click2(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'do stuff
End Sub
```

set the value of the tag's keyvaluepair value to false, to have the sub routine remove the handler from that controls click event

Comment: I appreciate it, but the code you show me does not help me for my purpose, because they expect to eliminate all handles of a control, but I need to delete one handle of an specific Sub, For example: if I have "MySub() handles Button1.Click" and also "MyFunc() handles Button1.Click" then with your suggestion it will delete the same handle in the Sub and in the Func, but I only want to delete the handle on MySub() and preserve the other "Button1.Click" in MyFunc, question: The original code does what I need?

Comment: First off, you can't use a function as an event handler it has to be a sub.  Secondly what conditions do you have that require the event handler to be changed?  Also if the change is simple and known you can use the RemoveHandler method

Comment: My fault about the function, but anyways what I need to do is to remove all the handlers which are handled in a Sub, not all the handlers of a Control. For example something like this: **For each hdl as handler in MethodName : removehandler hdl** do you understand me now? thanks

Comment: I think it's getting clearer now.  You want to remove a handler from each control that has an event tied to it.  Is it known which controls have events tied to that handler?  What you could do is, don't use the handles clause, set the handlers in the form load event with the addhandler statement.  for each control that you add the handler to set the tag object to be a dictionary(of string, Boolean) and add an entry to identify which event and handler it's using with the Boolean set to true for instance .Add("click-1", true) every button that has "click-1" set to true remove it's click handler.

Comment: I'm specific looking for a generic way to do it. PS: Sorry my english is not always the correct words, that's exactly what I want to do but i need a generic way 'cause my sub is event handling more than one control event.

Comment: When you say more than one event I assume that for instance you're handling the click event of different types of controls with one handler.  I modified my code to work with any control.  I didn't put any error trapping in case you have a control that doesn't have a click event.  The code is fairly straight forward your should be able to modify it for you needs.